# Issue with QHash

Tags: c++, qt

I been trying and trying to get this to work but it just refuses to work. I read the QT documentation and I'm just unable to get the insert function to function. When I build I get the following complication errors

```
/home/mmanley/projects/StreamDesk/libstreamdesk/SDDatabase.cpp: In constructor 'SDDatabase::SDDatabase()':
/home/mmanley/projects/StreamDesk/libstreamdesk/SDDatabase.cpp:27:44: error: no matching function for call to 'QHash<QString, SDChatEmbed>::insert(const char [9], SDChatEmbed (&)())'
/usr/include/qt4/QtCore/qhash.h:751:52: note: candidate is: QHash<Key, T>::iterator         QHash<Key, T>::insert(const Key&, const T&) [with Key = QString, T = SDChatEmbed]
make[2]: *** [libstreamdesk/CMakeFiles/streamdesk.dir/SDDatabase.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [libstreamdesk/CMakeFiles/streamdesk.dir/all] Error 2
```

here is the header file:

```
class SDStreamEmbed {
        Q_OBJECT
    public:
        SDStreamEmbed();
        SDStreamEmbed(const SDStreamEmbed &other);

        QString FriendlyName() const;

        SDStreamEmbed &operator=(const SDStreamEmbed &other) {return *this;}
        bool operator==(const SDStreamEmbed &other) const {return friendlyName == other.friendlyName;}

    private:
        QString friendlyName;
};

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(SDStreamEmbed)

inline uint qHash(const SDStreamEmbed &key) {
    return qHash(key.FriendlyName());
}
```

and the implementation

```
SDStreamEmbed::SDStreamEmbed() {

}

SDStreamEmbed::SDStreamEmbed(const SDStreamEmbed& other) {

}

QString SDStreamEmbed::FriendlyName() const {
    return friendlyName;
}
```

and how I am invoking it

```
SDChatEmbed embedTest();
ChatEmbeds.insert("DemoTest", embedTest);
```

and the definition of ChatEmbeds

```
QHash<QString, SDStreamEmbed> StreamEmbeds;
```

Comment: is 
**ChatEmbeds.insert(QString("DemoTest"), embedTest);** working ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace:

```
SDChatEmbed embedTest();
```

with:

```
SDChatEmbed embedTest;
```

The compiler interprets the first line as a function declaration. This is visible in the error message: it deduces the following type for the second argument:

```
SDChatEmbed (&)()
```

and that's a function signature.

I don't think you need an explicit `QString` cast/construction for the first argument since `QString` has a constructor that takes a `const char*`, so that one should get converted automatically.

(See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424510/most-vexing-parse-why-doesnt-a-a-work) for some interesting info.)

Comment: OHHH wow, its always the most simple syntax stuff that makes it fail.   Thank you, would have took me hours and I'd still not think of that, being from a C# background C++ is a bit confusing at times. And thanks for the additional information to help me understand why its like that, very helpful.